# Modifying data type from varchar(int) to date and time

Tags: sql

I have a column which I believe has been declared wrongly in SQL. It contains data and I do not wish to lose the data.  I wish to change the definition from varchar(int) to date and time. I was under the impression I cannot just alter the column type?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're asking about SQL Server, you can just alter the column as long as all the data in that column can be automatically converted by SQL Server to the new type.

If the data cannot be converted automatically (as it contains strings that are not valid date and times), you will need to do the following:

1. Create a new column of one of datetime data types.
2. Transform the data from the old to the new column.
3. Drop the old column.
4. Rename the new column to the old column's name.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming SQL server RDBMS, make sure you take backup of the table.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable
  ALTER COLUMN YourColumnName datetime
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this its just an example:

```
Alter Table testing
Add some_dt DateTime Default('1900-01-01') NOT NULL
GO

Update testing
    Set some_dt = Convert(DateTime,Tmp_some_dt)
GO

Alter Table testing
    DROP Column Tmp_some_dt
GO

select * from testing
go
```